# Visual Studio debugger - override the variable preview bubble?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I would like to replace it with my own. I'm referring to the bubble that pops over a variable when you mouse-over it, during a debugging session, when hitting a breakpoint. Is it possible to toggle it off ?

Comment: I manage to make it disppear by holding the ALT key while moving the mouse. But I'd like to do better than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution : using GlobalCbtHook (https://github.com/arlm/Global-CbtHook), i can intercept the creation of the window and close it before it appears.

Comment: Approved ! Well done